# How to set up different key to be pressed on same program?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I'd like to set a different key from keyboard on the same program. The key is always to be pressed (like put a heavy object on the key).

Let's say that I open two MS.Word. I'd like to auto press `A` on the first ms.word and press `B` on another ms.word. The button must also always be pressed.

The ms.word is just an example. It should be working on another program like notepad, mozilla etc

Comment: I don't understand, you just want to hold down a letter on the keyboard? Doesn't that work now, with your finger? Tried accessibility options, like sticky keys?

Comment: Right now it is very unclear what you are asking. Please use the EDIT button to change your question, making it more clear and adding more information to help us understand what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited it. Feel free to ask me about the question I asked.

Comment: @Xen2050 I want to press `A` on the first program and press `B` on the second program on the same time

Answer (score 1):

To do this in AutoHotkey you can create a blocking or non-blocking hotkey that will send different keystrokes to different windows.  You can also make the hotkey exclusive to the window(s) of interest.

This could be performed by activating the windows back and forth (and sending to the active window), or by using ControlSend to send the keystrokes or commands to a hidden/inactive window once the second window title or hwnd is known.